# Can I import a mysql 5.4 dump file into mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have an old backup (mysqldump) file from mysql 5.6. Can I import it in MySql 8.0? What precautions should I take?
I was searching mysql document but could not find any reference instead come to know that database can not be upgraded directly from mysql version 5.6 to 8.0

mysql -uUSERNAME -p DB_NAME < mysql5.6_dumpfile.sql

Comment: What is the problem you have when you try to import a dump from MySQL 5.6 into a MySQL 8.0 server? Please [edit] your question to include any detail and/or error messages you get. Also include a minimal dump file which produce the error you get.

Comment: It might be the same as me. I cannot import Chinese anymore, After Mysql 5.7 came 8.0 and importing Chinese is getting impossible. I tried many language settings, if not solved within a month I need to consider another database for all customers, that's expensive.